# navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemSelectedListener)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKhN8.png)
how can i run "navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemSelectedListener)"
code

i tried everything but i cant find a solution

Answer (score 0):

You need below structure to make it work:

```
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var mNavController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val bottomNavView: BottomNavigationView = binding.bottomNavView
        mNavController = findNavController(R.id.fragment_host)
        // Add your navHost fragment
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.homeFragment,
                R.id.dashboardFragment,
                R.id.profileFragment
            )
        )
        //Change fragments with yours
        setupActionBarWithNavController(mNavController, appBarConfiguration)
        bottomNavView.setupWithNavController(mNavController)

        bottomNavView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
            NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, mNavController)
            mNavController.popBackStack(item.itemId, inclusive = false)
            true
        }

    }
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jCN-Fh8ugXQ&list=PLxefhmF0pcPnPuhlBPBq_FdG2GXpgrhVJ&index=2&ab_channel=CodingCafe watch this i cant do it

Comment: It is very old tutorial, a lot has changed. Correct usage of it is the way my answer coded. But still if you want to follow that tutorial, i solved your question, in your other question's answer. You asked it twice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74558103/4058604)