# bottomnavigatonview Problem android studio kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

[image]
Please help me

i tried everything but it didnt work

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Answer (score 0):

You should put your `setupNavigation` outside of `onCreate`. And correct usage of it like below:

```
        fun setupNavigation(context: Context, bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView) {
            bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(object: BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
                override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
                    when (item.itemId) {
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```